# Getting error while running rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using ruby 1.9.2 and I am getting following error while running rake db:migrate command

found unknown escape character while parsing a quoted scalar at line ...

Anybody have any idea why this error is coming ?

Comment: Can you post first lines of your error message.

Comment: You can add the `--trace` switch to your command to get detailed error messages, might be helpful

Answer (score 2):

please use `bundle exec rake db:migrate` command for db migration.